# NoMachine over SSH/Netcat proxy

Tags: ssh-tunnel, nx

I am tunneling an nc connection to my target host (example.com) over an ssh connection to my gateway. Below is my .ssh/config setup for this connection:

```
Host target
Hostname example.com
HostKeyAlias target
ProxyCommand ssh me@gateway /bin/nc example.com 22
```

This is great and allows me to ssh to the target host in one step. What I would like to do is be able to tunnel an NX or VNC session over this connection.

Anyone know how this might be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use port forwarding that SSH already can do:

```
ssh -L 5900:example.com:5900 me@gateway
```

This will forward port 5900 from your local machine to example.com through gateway.
Now just "vncviewer localhost" from your local machine.

Comment: much easier than my solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how a VNC session can be created over an ssh tunnel with a gateway hop in between the client and target machines:

/etc/ssh/sshd_config (on target machine) must have these lines:

```
X11Forwarding yes
XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
```

Your path to xauth may be different, but by default sshd looks in the wrong location so this value should be set.

.ssh/config (on the client machine):

```
Host example.com
Hostname foo.example.com
HostKeyAlias example.com
ProxyCommand ssh -t -C me@gateway.com /bin/nc %h 22
```

Then from the client I can run

```
me@localhost$ ssh -X -C example.com
```

This starts an X session on my client as well as an ssh connection to example.com. Now, just a couple more commands on the remote host to bring up VNC:

```
me@example.com$ vncserver :n 
me@example.com$ vncviewer -encodings "copyrect tight zlib corre rre raw" :n
```

In the above commands, :n is is the display number where you want to start vnc and the display where vncviewer should look for the vnc session. Since this looks like a local connection to VNC it is a good idea to specify some better encodings as vncviewer will default to raw, giving poor performance over the network.

That's it!

Comment: http://fixunix.com/ssh/73746-problem-tunneling-vnc-through-ssh-via-gateway.html